# Excluding certain time periods in Excel

Tags: date, datetime, time, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm currently trying to work out a function that will keep track of how much time was spent working on the delivery of a client. Employees provide me with the date and time they started working on the delivery and the date and time they finished the job.

I process this information in the current way:

- Column 1 contains "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" for time started

  Column 2 contains "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" for time finished

Now, we only work during certain hours of the day: we start at 7:15 and finish work at 16:45, there's also a 30 minute break from 12:00 'till 12:30.
Aside from that, we only work on weekdays, so any time period that falls in the weekend should not be calculated.

Calculating if the break was part of the time period was easily handled and I also found a way to ensure the 14:30 are subtracted if one day passes, but I can't figure out how to make it so that orders that take multiple days to prepare should be calculated.

An example set of data (start - end ==> total (hh:mm))

Mon 23/02/2015 07:45 - Mon 23/02/2015 10:05 ==> 02:20

Tue 24/02/2015 11:50 - Tue 24/02/2015 15:35 ==> 03:15 (0:30 subtracted due to break)

Wed 25/02/2015 14:45 - Thu 26/02/2015 07:45 ==> 02:30 (14:30 subtracted due to end of day)

Fri 27/02/2015 16:00 - Mon 02/03/2015 07:45 ==> 01:15 (62:30 subtracted due to weekend)

Mon 30/03/2015 13:20 - Wed 01/04/2015 12:00 ==> 17:10 (29:30 subtracted: 2 days and 1 break)

The first three cases are handled by my current code, but I can't figure out how to make it calculate the last two.

I use an additional column to check if the break was between the two times ( A3 contains =TEXT(A1;"dd/mm/yyyy ")&"12:00" and the function to check is =IF(AND(A2>A3;A3>A1);"0:30";0)

Column 4 contains data to check for the next day: A4 contains =TEXT(A1+"24:00";"dd/mm/yyyy ")&"7:15" and the function to check is =IF(A2>A4;"14:30";0)

As you might see, this poses a problem when a weekend passes or multiple days are needed to complete an order.

My sincere thanks in advance to anyone taking the time to work on this; I've been breaking my brains on this for a week now.

Kind regards,
Feng

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it I think is to use NETWORKDAYS to get the number of days (complete or incomplete) spent working on the project, then subtract the parts of days not spent on it.

I've chosen to break it down into four separate formulae.

Number of days or part-days spent (converted into time) in C2

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)*9/24
```

Time to be subtracted from start day in D2

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),0)<=TIME(12,0,0),TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),0)-TIME(7,15,0),TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),0)-TIME(7,45,0))
```

Time to be subtracted from end day in E2

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),0)<=TIME(12,0,0),TIME(16,15,0)-TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),0),TIME(16,45,0)-TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),0))
```

Then the result in F2

```
=C2-D2-E2
```

I'm assuming that times in the lunch break or out of hours can't occur.

[image]